# AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'show'

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

```
import PIL.Image
im01 = open('circle.jpg')
im01.show()
```

This code has not showing the image like I expected it would.  Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The built-in function 'open' returns an object of '_io.TextIOWrapper' which doesn't have a 'show' attribute. basically you are not using the module you imported

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong [open](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#open-rotate-and-display-an-image-using-the-default-viewer) method.  It should look like this:

```
from PIL import Image
im01 = Image.open('circle.jpg')
im01.show()
```